# How I can call the any script on Microsoft HDInsight Cluster delete event

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight

I Want to execute some script on HDInsight Cluster before delete or after delete.
This should be get call If I delete cluster using Azure Web UI and cluster Delete API also.

Using script action I can execute script but at the time of cluster creation only but not at the time of cluster deletion.

Comment: Can you explain a bit in detail ,what does this script do?

Answer (score 0):

Did you think about using `hdinsight rest api` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/hdinsight/scriptactions/clusters/executescriptactions#examples  and then automate it with `ADF` using `web activity`

[image]

**Or** Using Powershell https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-customize-cluster-linux#apply-a-script-action-to-a-running-cluster-from-azure-powershell and automate it using ADF Custom activity https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/106584/executing-powershell-script-throuh-azure-data-fact.html

And then you can delete the cluster using rest-api-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/hdinsight/clusters/delete

**Or** Powershell-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.hdinsight/remove-azurermhdinsightcluster?view=azurermps-6.13.0

Note: You should have the cluster name handy(The above steps might get complex for the on-Demand cluster)

Comment: @Shramik If the solution fits your requirement, please mark it as an answer so that it can also helpful for others.